# Exchange 2010 MRM and Personal Archives

Tags: windows, exchange, exchange-2010, windows-server-2012, email

We are preparing to go live with MRM on Exchange 2010. Our DPT will be to delete after 90 days. We've also enabled personal archives. Currently, we have our retention policies in place but only to mark items as past their retention limit. We just noticed that items in the archive are showing expiration dates and policy being applied. Does this mean when we go live that those items past their retention limit will be deleted from the archive too?

Comment: OK, how about if we all just agree to stop using acronyms. What is MRM and DPT?

Comment: Sorry about that, "Messaging Records Management" and "Default Policy Tag".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer to my question after logs of googling. Yes, this will affect the archive as well, so we're reevaluating our policy.